# How can I shorten an if then else using the [] format

Tags: ls, bashrc

I want to shorten this to a one liner:

```
if ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils'; then alias ls='ls --color=always'
else alias ls='ls -G'
fi
```

I frequently use `[]` for conditionals, e.g. `[ -z(or -n) condition]` but haven't had to do an else part in this format yet.

In ruby I would do `condition ? true : false`  Is there an equivalent in bash?

I tried

```
[ -z ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils'] ? alias ls='ls --color=always' : alias ls='ls -G'
```

but obviously that's not the right way to do it.

I want a one-liner because I want all my `.bashrc` to fit in a smallish window (< ~50 lines) so, as with other multi-liners I condense them into one liners when possible.  I am comfortable with sacrificing readability for size for this example.

I also tried:

```
[ -z ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils'] && alias ls='ls --color=always' || alias ls='ls -G'
```

and

```
[ -n ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils'] && alias ls='ls --color=always' || alias ls='ls -G'
```

and

```
[ ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils'] && alias ls='ls --color=always' || alias ls='ls -G'
```

but I always get the 'else' alias not the 'then' alias

I could just reverse it but I suspect that as it's not working right that wouldn't help.  Only way to be sure though is to try it on OSX and I'm on ubuntu right now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tl;dr;

Use

```
ls --color=always > /dev/null 2>&1 && alias ls='ls --color=always' || alias ls='ls -G'`
```

Details....
`[...]` are only needed to evaluate conditional expressions (stats of files, string comparisons, numeric comparisons; see `CONDITIONAL EXPRESSIONS` in `bash(1)`). They would also be needed for that in a `if ... ; then ...; else` construct.

For relatively simple constructs

```
if CONDITION; then
    EXPR1
else
    EXPR2
fi
```

can be replaced by

```
CONDITION && EXPR1 || EXPR2
```

If you do not need `[...]` in the first case, you do not need it for the second.

In your case `CONDITION` is `ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils'`, that is the return code of `grep`. So you can just write

```
ls --version 2>/dev/null | grep -q 'coreutils' && alias ls='ls --color=always' || alias ls='ls -G'
```

BTW: It would be easier to check if `ls` supports `--color` directly:

```
ls --color=always > /dev/null 2>&1 && alias ls='ls --color=always' || alias ls='ls -G'
```

Comment: Not just for arithmetic - eg http://www.tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_07_01.html

Comment: @JoshJolly Thanks for the catch, it should of course be *conditional expressions*.

Comment: Note that you should only use that (and IMO, it's better not to use that at all) if you can guarantee that `EXPR1` will always return true as otherwise `EXPR2` will also be executed.

Answer (score 1):

With `zsh`, it can be compressed to:

```
if {ls --version|&grep -q coreutils} {alias ls='ls --color=always'
} else {alias ls='ls -G'}
```

The `cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3` construct as a replacement for if/then/else should generally be avoided as it's not the same at all.

In

```
cmd1 && cmd2 || cmd3`
```

`cmd2` is executed if `cmd1` returns `true`. And `cmd3` is executed if either of `cmd1` **or `cmd2`** returns false.

In your case `cmd2` (`alias`) is very unlikely to return false, but it's easy to forget about the problem in the general case, so it's best to avoid that construct in the first place.

The only *real* reason where it may be useful is when you want to write code that works in both Bourne-like and csh-like shells (or `rc`-like ones where that works as well) where the `if/then/else` construct have different syntax.